# Stop gdb from echoing commands to the prompt with a "+" prefix

Tags: emacs, gdb

When loading `.gdbinit`, gdb prints out the config lines with a "+" prefix, as well as echos any command I type with a "+" prefix. How do I stop it from printing these lines? See an example below.

This becomes an issue when I use editor integration - specifically tried with emacs - where it calls "info break" in the background. It is printed on the console as "+info break" in a continuous stream, making the gdb prompt unusable.

```
+set history remove-duplicates 1
+set history filename ~/.gdb_history
+set disassembly-flavor intel
+set print pretty on
+skip file allocator.h
File allocator.h will be skipped when stepping.
+skip file auto_ptr.h
File auto_ptr.h will be skipped when stepping.
+skip file basic_string.h
File basic_string.h will be skipped when stepping.
+skip file basic_string.tcc
File basic_string.tcc will be skipped when stepping.
+skip file move.h
File move.h will be skipped when stepping.
+skip file range_access.h
File range_access.h will be skipped when stepping.
+skip file shared_ptr.h
...
(gdb) s
+s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When loading .gdbinit, gdb prints out the config lines with a "+" prefix, as well as echos any command I type with a "+" prefix. How do I stop it from printing these lines?

GDB *does not* do this by default. You have some setting in your `~/.gdbinit` which causes GDB to do this (most likely: `set trace-commands on`).

Solution: remove that setting.

Comment: I have added `set trace-commands on` to my `.gdbinit` file. Removing it solves the issue. Thank you!